# How to go from np.tensordot to np.einsum

Tags: python, numpy-einsum

What I have in the code I was given is something like:

```
C = np.tensordot(B, A, axes = (0,0))
```

A is a `(20L, 50L)` and B is `(20L, 20L)`

I was supposed to change since someone told me it would be faster with `np.einsum`, but I guess I don't fully understand what `tensordot` is outputing.

Right now C is a `(20L, 50L)` and I don't understand why?

Of course I have read the documentation page, but still didn't grasp the information. Take into consideration that I have just started working with Python.

Answer (score 0):

With A having shape (20,50) and B having shape (20,20):

```
C = np.tensordot(B, A, axes = (0,0))
```

is equivalent to:

```
C = np.zeros((20,50))
for i in range(20):
    for j in range(50):
        for k in range(20):
            C[i,j] += A[k,j] * B[k,i]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
C = np.einsum('kj,ki->ij',A,B)
```

einsum indeed seems to be a bit quicker than tensordot:

```
%timeit np.einsum('kj,ki->ij',A,B)
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.1 µs per loop

%timeit np.tensordot(B,A,axes=(0,0))
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.6 µs per loop
```